# Animations with Functions for Pygames

Tags: python, python-2.7

Read the text for using functions to draw objects, modify your code from a previous lab such that a function is defined to draw an object.  The function should take in a single pair of x, y parameters that serve as the basis of location for the object.

Adjust the animation loop in your main code to ultilize your function to draw multiple instances of  the object.
The problem I am having is trying to recode this using functions i am not sure how to do this.
Here is my code:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:         Animations.py
# Purpose:      Draws a picture of a farm and shooting star that moves and makes it rain while the song Raining Men
#
# Author:   
#
# Created:      12/10/2013
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER']= 'windib'
#Imports OS
import random
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("The_Weather_Girls_It_39_s_Raining_Men.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
#Initiates music mixer and plays music

black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
dsblue   = (   0, 191, 255)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)
green    = (   0, 255,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
sbrown   = ( 139,  69,  19)
fbrick   = ( 178,  34,  34)
yellow   = ( 255, 255,   0)
hgrey    = (  30,  30,  30)
hyellow  = ( 255, 255, 102)
#Defines colours

done = False

shooting_star_x = 0
shooting_star_y = 50
#Starting position of shooting star

shooting_star_change_x = 10
shooting_star_change_y = 10
#Speed and direction of shooting star

size = [700,500]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
#Sets the screen

pygame.display.set_caption("The Big Red Farm!")
#Sets header for pygame

rain_list = []

for i in range(100):
    x = random.randrange(0,700)
    y = random.randrange(0,700)
    rain_list.append([x,y])

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#Sets clock to manage how fast screen updates

#Program Loop ----------------------------------------------------------
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #If clicked close
            print ("User asked to quit.")
            done = True
            #Terminates loop

    screen.fill(hgrey)
#Sets background colour to a dark grey

    pygame.draw.circle(screen,hyellow, (130, 80),55)
#Draws the moon

    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen,white,[shooting_star_x,shooting_star_y,150,5])
    print shooting_star_y
    shooting_star_x += shooting_star_change_x
    if shooting_star_x <= 699:
        shooting_star_x += shooting_star_change_x
    elif shooting_star_x >= 700:
        shooting_star_x = 25
        shooting_star_x += shooting_star_change_x
    elif shooting_star_x >= 300:
        screen.fill(red)
#Draws Shooting star

    pygame.draw.rect   (screen,red,[300,200,400,300])
#Draws farm

    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen,red,[300,100,400,200])
#Draws roof

    pygame.draw.rect   (screen, sbrown, [475,350,75,150])
#Draws Door

    pygame.draw.rect   (screen,  yellow, [350,200,20,20])
    pygame.draw.rect   (screen,  yellow, [375,200,20,20])
    pygame.draw.rect   (screen,  yellow, [350,225,20,20])
    pygame.draw.rect   (screen,  yellow, [375,225,20,20])
#Draws the window on the top left side of the big red farm

    pygame.draw.rect   (screen,  yellow, [610,200,20,20])
    pygame.draw.rect   (screen,  yellow, [635,200,20,20])
    pygame.draw.rect   (screen,  yellow, [610,225,20,20])
    pygame.draw.rect   (screen,  yellow, [635,225,20,20])
#Draws the window on the top right side of the big red farm

    pygame.draw.rect   (screen,  yellow, [350,350,60,100])
#Draws the window on the left bottom part of the big red farm

    pygame.draw.rect   (screen,  yellow, [600,350,60,100])
#Draws the window on the right bottom part of the big red farm

    pygame.draw.rect   (screen,red,     [0,295,300,500])
#Draws the garage that is attached to the big red barn

    pygame.draw.rect   (screen, sbrown, [65,400,190,400])
#Draws the garage door

    for i in range(len(rain_list)):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,dsblue, rain_list[i],2)
        rain_list[i][1] += 3

        if rain_list[i][1] > 700:
            y = random.randrange(-50,-10)
            rain_list[i][1] = y
            x = random.randrange(0,700)
            rain_list[1][0] = x

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(165)

pygame.quit()
#Terminates program
```

Comment: What issue are you having? You can't just show your assignment and your code and expect us to psychically know what is going on. You need to say what problem you're encountered with your current solution. If you're getting an exception, please include the full traceback in your question. If you're having some other issue, tell us what it is!

Comment: my assignment is due tonight and i am not sure how to re code the coding with functions @Blckknght

Comment: @Blckknght do u think you can assist me with this